# SITE: Search Google Index Mobile VS Desktop

Tags: seo, google, google-index

So I noticed something weird yesterday...when doing a `site: www.example.com` search on google yesterday, it returned TWICE the amount of pages compared to doing a desktop `site:search` am I just really behind the times here or are there 2 seperate indexes? If not I may have just found proof there is!

Furthermore, any likely reasons that the mobile `site:search` returned so many more results than the desktop search

Comment: *Are there 2 separate indexes?* **No.** Just two separate domain names, www.example.com and example.com. Your site is being found both ways. I have no idea what you mean by *mobile site:search*.

Comment: I did a site search on my desktop and a site search on my mobile, which delivered significantly different results

Comment: Okay. I got it. DUH! ;-) A search on a mobile device should return mobile friendly pages.

Comment: Ok but why hare more than 30% of my pages indexed on mobile but not on desktop...

Comment: `site:` only show's a portion of an index. Mobile results are different and subject to a set of modified algorithms. Use Webmaster Tools to determine index problems, not `site:`.

Comment: Simon is absolutely right! The SERPs are a result of a series of blended search queries that then pass through a bunch of algorithms and filters. What algorithms and filters are used change from desktop to mobile.